# Installing gym[atari] in a virtualenv

Tags: python, linux, virtualenv, gentoo, openai-gym

I'm having trouble installing gym-atari in a virtualenv.  From what I can tell, it *looks* like the issue is with zlib, but zlib is installed on the system (so is cmake).  Anyone have any ideas?  This is on a Gentoo system, for what it's worth:

```
(tensorflow)alaya ~ # pip install gym[atari] 
Requirement already satisfied: gym[atari] in     /opt/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages 
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages (from gym[atari]) 
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.0 in /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages (from gym[atari]) 
Requirement already satisfied: pyglet>=1.2.0 in /opt/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from gym[atari]) 
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.10.4 in /opt/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from gym[atari]) 
Requirement already satisfied: PyOpenGL; extra == "atari" in /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages (from gym[atari]) 
Collecting atari-py>=0.0.17; extra == "atari" (from gym[atari])   Using cached atari-py-0.0.18.tar.gz 
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow; extra == "atari" in /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages (from gym[atari]) 
Building wheels for collected packages: atari-py   
Running setup.py bdist_wheel for atari-py ... error   
Complete output from command /opt/tensorflow/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-Xd0Ga4/atari-py/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpCxn1j3pip-wheel- --python-tag cp27: 
. 
. 
.
[  9%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ale-bin.dir/src/common/display_screen.cpp.o   
In file included from /tmp/pip-build-Xd0Ga4/atari-py/atari_py/ale_interface/src/emucore/unzip.c:13:0: /tmp/pip-build-Xd0Ga4/atari-py/atari_py/ale_interface/src/emucore/unzip.h:114:45: 
error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'OF'    extern int ZEXPORT unzStringFileNameCompare OF ((const char* fileName1,
                                               ^   
/tmp/pip-build-Xd0Ga4/atari-py/atari_py/ale_interface/src/emucore/unzip.h:127:32: 
error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'OF'    extern unzFile ZEXPORT unzOpen OF((const char *path));
                                  ^   
/tmp/pip-build-Xd0Ga4/atari-py/atari_py/ale_interface/src/emucore/unzip.h:138:29: 
error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'OF'    extern int ZEXPORT unzClose OF((unzFile file)); 
. . .
```

Any ideas?  My only guess is that somehow zlib isn't getting pulled into the virtualenv???  Maybe it's not even zlib though?

Comment: Asking this question rang a bell for me; I had a similar problem trying to install ALE on my Gentoo box.  The solution is to modify unzip.h but I don't know how to do that.

I'll open a new thread and try to link to it from here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O.k., so this was in the end a Gentoo issue -- I'll post the solution in case anyone else has it.

Following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20685797/breaking-pip-install-to-smaller-steps-so-i-can-edit-the-package-before-it-is) (with atari-py instead of netifaces) I was able to get a version of the package I could edit.  I then added the following to the top of /tmp/atari-py-0.0.18/atari_py/ale_interface/src/emucore/unzip.h:

```
/* Gentoo removed OF from their copy of zconf.h     (https://bugs.gentoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=383179) */
/* but our copy of minizip needs it. */
#ifndef OF
#define OF(args) args
#endif
```

then running pip install . from /tmp/atari-py-0.0.18 did the trick.

Comment: thanks, this worked for me too. I cloned atari-py from github, changed code as you suggested and did "pip install ." worked like a charm on my gentoo

Answer (score 0):

For anyone in the future, if the chosen answer does not solve your problem, make sure you have `cmake` installed. `sudo apt install cmake` on ubuntu/debian.